# Menu click to show div with same id: variable scope issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu

I'm new to jQuery and javascript, so pardon the code's inelegance, but I'm trying to get a handle on it and would appreciate anyone's help.

I'm trying to create a tabbed menu that takes the id of the clicked menu item and shows a content div with the same id. I got it working with code blocks for each individual menu item and paired content div, but I'm trying to add variables so that the matching id can be specified on the fly and used to select and show the correct content div.

```
    var clickedId;
    var storedMenu;
    var storedContent;
    $(".nav ul li").click(function() {
       clickedId = $(this).attr("id");
       storedMenu = ("nav ul li#" + clickedId);
       storedContent = (".content div#" + clickedId);
    }); 

    $(storedMenu).click(function(){
        if ($(storedContent).hasClass("hidden")) 
            {
            $(".content div:not('.hidden')").toggleClass("hidden");
            $(storedContent).toggleClass("hidden");
            $(".nav ul li:not('.filed')").toggleClass("filed");
            $(storedMenu).toggleClass("filed");
            }
    });
```

The variables now have the value I want them to when I check them in the console, but are apparently not passing to the second click function.

Just for reference, here's the functioning template for an individual item:

```
    $(".nav ul li#main").click(function(){
        if ($(".content div#main").hasClass("hidden")) 
            {
            $(".content div:not('.hidden')").toggleClass("hidden");
            $(".content div#main").toggleClass("hidden");
            $(".nav ul li:not('.filed')").toggleClass("filed");
            $(".nav ul li#main").toggleClass("filed");
            }
    });
```

And here's a jsFiddle with the non-functioning variable version (including html and css): http://jsfiddle.net/BHAyc/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: ID's **must** be unique :D

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Comment: Okay, but renaming all the content ids "main2" etc. and adding "2" to the variable doesn't make it work.

That's more of a "best practice" issue than a "code won't work" issue, isn't it? The non-variable version shouldn't have worked if that were the case, as I'm using shared IDs there, too.

Comment: @putvande It's in the jsFiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would ditch the id for the tabs (unless you need an individual style for each) and use anchor links so you can easily reference the content that needs to appear, also I would use a class to mark the active tab instead of the other way around

**HTML**

```
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="#main">Main</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#work">Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="#blog">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.nav li{
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.nav li.active{
    border-bottom: 0
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$(".nav ul li a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //hide all content
    $('.content > div').addClass('hidden');
    //remove active link
    $('.nav ul li.active').removeClass('active')
    //show target content
    $($(this).attr('href')).removeClass('hidden');
    //mark tab as active
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
});
```

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BHAyc/4/)**

Comment: Thanks! I'm marking this response since you modified and simplified my own (bad!) code, which helps me understand what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need unique IDs, that's the point of ID.

Try giving the div an ID derived from the menu item's ID, like this:

Menu item has ID=page13
Content div to be shown has ID=content-page13

All you have to do is to add "content-" into the selector and div's ID, and it will work.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Adding 2 to the end of the content div names (e.e. 'main2') and using 'storedContent = (".content div#" + clickedId + "2");' doesn't seem to be working, tho...

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have 2 elements with the same ID on a page. The ID attribute is supposed to be unique. Also, you can use pure css if you wanted to using the href="#ID_OF_DIV" in your links and a CSS snippet to hide and show content.

I used "nav-ID_OF_DIV" for the li (menu ids), in the JavaScript a remove the "nav-" prefix of the id with a regular expression replace /^nav-/.

http://jsfiddle.net/BHAyc/1/

JS

```
// hide all content
$(".content > div").hide();
// show the first content div
$(".content > div:first").show();

$(".nav ul li").click(function() {
   clickedId = $(this).attr("id");
   // remove the nav- prefix
   clickedId = clickedId.replace(/^nav-/, "");
   // hide all content
   $(".content > div").hide();
   // show the current selected one
   $(".content > div#"+clickedId).show();
   // add filed class to all the nav li's
   $(".nav ul li").addClass("filed");
   // remove filed from clicked li
   $(this).removeClass("filed");
});
```

CSS

```
.content > div {
    display: none;
}
.content > div:target {
    display: block;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li id="nav-main"><a href="#main">Main</a></li>
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @LastCoder. There are a few things in here I'll definitely use.  Do you have any examples of how to do this with pure CSS? Everything I've seen says there's no way to trigger click events without javascript.

Comment: @stefifofum - the pure css code is in there. using href="#ID_OF_DIV" on your A tags and the CSS with ":target".

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. I thought "pure css" meant css unaided by js/jQuery. Thanks again!

Comment: @stefifofum - it does, if you used the CSS noted in my answer and JUST a tags a href="#ID_OF_DIV" you would have tabbing functionality. Here's a good explaination http://css-tricks.com/css3-tabs/